# Why does this command not take input from file inspite of rediection?

Tags: bash, shell, input, terminal, io-redirection

On executing, the cisco anyconnect VPN client takes the VPN IP, password, and some other inputs from the terminal. However, instead of typing it every time, I wrote down the values in a file and tried to redirect the file into the vpn client command.

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn < vpndetails.txt
```

However, it seems that the command ignores the file redirection and still prompts for input. How is it possible? Does the code read from some other file-descriptor (not 0) and still reads it from the terminal? Is it possible?

Note: I know it isn't a good practice to store your passwords in a file, but I don't care for now.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible if the inputs are provided as `arguments` to the command? i guess it would make things easy..

Comment: When a process is started by an interactive shell, that process inherits its stdin from the tty.  Your redirection changes the behavior so that the process' stdin is the file.  However, the tty still exists, and it looks like `vpn` is simply reading from it directly, rather than reading from stdin.  For a simple example, write a script that reads from `/dev/tty`

Comment: One possibility is that the `vpn` command resets the standard input before actually attempting to prompt for `VPN IP` etc. . . So, then you should try something different, like `(sleep 1 ; printf "192.168.56.2\n" ; sleep 1; printf "asecret\n" ; ...) |  /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn`

Comment: @Jayjargot That doesn't work either.

Comment: @WilliamPursell why would it do that? Anyway, aren't there multiple terminals /dev/tty0, /dev/tty1 etc.?

Comment: If there is no "clean" way of supplying the settings to the VPN client such as using arguments or similar, you could consider writing an [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) script to automate user input.

Comment: @PriyankPalod There are multiple terminals, but `/dev/tty` (no trailing number) is typically the controlling terminal for the current process.

Comment: It would do that to ensure that passwords are being entered interactively, to prevent the security weakness introduced by people trying to put passwords in regular files.  Yes, there are multiple ttys.  `/dev/tty` is the current device (major 5, minor 0), and `/dev/ttyN` is a specific device.  (See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html)

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamPursell. While I am not sure if there is any way to find what the binary is actually doing without looking at the source code, I at least know one of the things it could be doing. Is there any way to be sure though? Can I write directly to /dev/tty such that the binary reads it (other than actually typing it, of course) ?

Comment: Lots of programs do this. `ssh` springs to mind. You can't pipe your password into ssh. If you really want to automate it, you can use [tag:expect], but there's most likely a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "Is it possible" has the answer "yes".

The code for the anyconnect vpn probably reads /dev/tty, as explained in the comments by Chepner e.a.As a fun exercise, try this script:

```
#! /bin/sh 

read -p "STDIN> " a
read -p "TERMINAL> " b  < /dev/tty
read -p "STDIN> " c

echo "Read $a and $c from stdio and $b from the terminal"
```

and, for example, `ls / | bash this_script.sh`.

However, if you wish to use Cisco Autoconnect without passwords, you should investigate the Always On with Trusted Network detection feature and user certificates.

Writing to `/dev/tty` in the hope that it will be picked-up by the script does not work:

```
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ ls | bash test.sh &
[3] 10558
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ echo 'plop' > /dev/tty
plop

[3]+  Stopped                 ls | bash test.sh
ljm@verlaine[tmp]$ fg
ls | bash test.sh
(a loose enter is given)
Read a_file and b_file from stdio and  from the terminal
```